# No Launcher Activity Found Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I got the Launcher tag, but my app still does not launching on compile from eclipse, what is the problem?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myproject.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

    <service android:name=".CurrentMoodService">
    </service>


    <receiver android:name=".CurrentMoodWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE"></category>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.myproject.test.widget.CurrentMoodService.MOODY" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/widgetproviderinfo" />
    </receiver>



    <activity
        android:name="com.myproject.test.MainTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.test.activities.Home"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.test.activities.Check"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.test.activities.Map"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.test.activities.Contact"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.test.activities.More"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.test.activities.About"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your manifest,in second lines you have write

```
package="com.priject.test"
```

and here package name is **com.myproject.test**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myproject.test.MainTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Make sure you have specified the correct package name :)

Comment: Well i just corrected the package names from originals to some random by posting here, so not this is the error sorry my bad.

Comment: just use  `android:name=".MainTabActivity"` instead of  `android:name="com.myproject.test.MainTabActivity"`. if you have already set the correct package name :)

Comment: :( java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, I hate the manifest file.

Comment: Its somehow works now, well i not clearly know what was the problem but thanks the help anyway!

Comment: @AndroidLearner Can we add data tag in Launcher activity for deep linking?